# Java BigInteger and the Shift operator

Tags: java, biginteger, bit-shift, ordinal

I have the enum;

```java
enum testMe {
    one,
    two,
    three;

    long longValue() {
        return 1<<ordinal();
    }
}

for (testMe myLoop = testMe.values()) {
    System.out.println(value.longValue() + ":" + myLoop);
}
```

Looping through the enum gives me exactly what I expect for the shift on the ordinal of the values in the enum. However, I need to qualify on an parameter I pass in a long;

```
Long myLong = 3;
for (testMe myLoop = testMe.values()) {
    if ((myLong & value.longValue()) != 0) {
        System.out.println(value.longValue() + ":" + myLoop);
    }
}
```

In this case only the One and Two will be printed. However, this method will only work to 32 values in the enum. Does anyone have any ideas how I could use the BigInteger???

```
    BigInteger longValue() {
        BigInteger one = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        return one.shiftLeft(ordinal());
```

Thanks C

Comment: Use `BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(ordinal())`?

Comment: *"Does anyone have any ideas how I could use the BigInteger?"* I don't really understand the question because you have included code that does this.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps I was a little unclear; the code that evaluates the if the ordinal should print the value of the enum...I do not seem to be able to get that to work.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with printing an enum or a BigInteger. see my updated answer. shiftLeft is OK as well, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  BigInteger b =BigInteger.ZERO;
  b = b.setBit( ordinal() );
```

You may also use BigInteger.and(BigInteger x).

```
enum OneTwo {
  one,
  two,
  three;

  BigInteger biValue() {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO;
    return bi.setBit(ordinal());
  }
  BigInteger biValue( BigInteger filter ) {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO;
    return bi.setBit(ordinal()).and(filter);
  }
}
```

And a test:

```
BigInteger three = BigInteger.valueOf(3L);
for (OneTwo ot: OneTwo.values()) {
    System.out.println( ot.biValue() + ":" + ot);
    System.out.println( ot.biValue(three) + ":" + ot);
}
```

No problem with printing.

Or compare to zero

```
if( BigInteger.ZERO.equals( bi.setBit(ordinal()).and(filter) ) ){
    // no bits in filter are set
}
```

Comment: Really like the method! How would I evaluate that ot.biValue(BigInteger.valueOf(three)) is not equal to zero?

Comment: @ChrisLuff Added boolean expression for comparing to zero

Answer (score 2):

Use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

```
EnumSet<TestMe> set = new EnumSet<>(TestMe.class);
```

An EnumSet has the bit properties you desire, though unfortunately does not exhibit them as `long[]` or such. Otherwise use a `BitSet`.

Comment: `BitSet` is a great idea because it's intended for this type of purpose where `BigInteger` is not.

Comment: @Radiodef Since BigInteger does have setBit and shiftLeft - how can you say it isn't "intended for this purpose"? If you want a *numeric* value at the end of the bit twiddling, BigInteger is much better than a BitSet or an EnumSet.

Comment: @laune sorry to see your answer deleted. My answer was more proposing an alternative to shifts, as this problem looks like forming a power **set**. Maybe undelete and have a bit of patience.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yeah, well, since I realized that it wouldn't really show much of an improvement I didn't see a point in keeping it. - Trying to solve set operations via some numeric representation is, of course, quite unnecessary.